# iostat equivalent for SCSI generic devices /dev/sg

Tags: linux, hard-drive, scsi

Is there any equivalent tool of `iostat` with which i can monitor I/O load on SCSI generic devices that do not have a block device?

I am interested in :

- operations per second reads/writes/others
- bandwidth per second reads/writes/others
- % busy time

Thanks

There is also a different tool called `iotop` which would be useful too to have for SCSI generic devices.